# Move or Hide unused extensions from Extensions tab to Add New tab

Tags: extension, plugin

Under System Settings > Extensions there is the first tab that shows up "Extensions" and there is another tab called "Add New".

Is it possible to remove unused extensions from this "extensions" tab and put them under the "add new" tab so that only the extensions I have enabled are visible on the "extensions" tab?

For example, I am not using the AuthX extension, so I do not need to see it everytime I go to the "extensions" tab.

Thanks